# Urwid: option for a button with different appearance

Tags: python, user-interface, button, text, colors

I would like to have a button in Urwid with uniform color (by default, the first letter is always color-reversed) and with characters lesser-than/greater-than replaced by spaces. Which options should I use, and if needed, what would be necessary for a custom button?